# Apache Spark broadcast variables are not reused

Tags: apache-spark

I face a weird behavior when using broadcast variables.  Each time I use a broadcasted variable, the content gets copied once for each node and is never reused.

Here is an example in spark-shell --master local[32]:
(Granted, it's useless and stupid code but it does show the behavior)

```
case class Test(a:String)
val test = Test("123")
val bc = sc.broadcast(test)

// On my 32 core machine, I get 33 copies of Test (expected)
// Yourkit profiler shows 33 instances of my object (32 are unreachable)
sc.parallelize((1 to 100)).map(x => bc.value.a).count

// Doing it again, Test copies are not reused and serialized again (now 65 copies, 64 are unreachable)
sc.parallelize((1 to 100)).map(x => bc.value.a).count
```

In my case, the variable I broadcast is several hundred megabytes and is composed of millions of small objects (few hashmaps and vectors).

Each time I run an operation on a RDD that use it, I get several gigabytes of memory wasted and the garbage collector is getting more and more of a bottleneck!

Is it by design to re-broadcast variables for each execution of a new closure or is it a bug and I should be reusing my copies?

Why are they unreachable immediatly after use?

It is particular to a spark-shell in local mode?

Note: I'm using spark-1.3.1-hadoop2.6

**Update1:**
According to this post: http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/How-to-share-a-NonSerializable-variable-among-tasks-in-the-same-worker-node-td11048.html
Singleton objects does not work anymore on Spark 1.2.x+ 
So this kind of workaround would not work either:

```
val bcModel = sc.broadcast(bigModel)
object ModelCache {
  @transient lazy private val localModel = { bcModel.value }
  def getModel = localModel
}
sc.parallelize((1 to 100)).map(x => ModelCache.getModel.someValue)
```

**Update2:**
I've also tried to reuse the accumulator pattern without success:

```
class VoidAccumulatorParams extends AccumulatorParam[BigModel] {
    override def addInPlace(r1: BigModel, r2: BigModel): BigModel= { r1 }
    override def zero(initialValue: BigModel): BigModel= { initialValue }
}
val acc = sc.accumulator(bigModel, "bigModel")(new VoidAccumulableParams())
sc.parallelize((1 to 100)).map(x => acc.localValue.someValue)
```

**Update3:**
**Looks like the singleton object works when running a job with spark-submit instead of the scala shell.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the broadcast tests ([BroadcastSuite.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.3.1/core/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/broadcast/BroadcastSuite.scala)) to see what to expect.

When you run the first job, your object is serialized, cut into chunks and the chunks are sent to the executors (through the BlockManager mechanism). They deserialize the object from the chunks and use it in processing the tasks. When they finish, they discard the *deserialized object*, but the BlockManager keeps the chunks of serialized data cached.

For the second job the object does not need to be serialized and transmitted. It's just deserialized from the cache and used.

---

Caveats: For one, this does not help you avoid the excessive GC. The other thing is, I tried to validate the above theory by using mutable state (`class Test(var a: String) extends Serializable`) and mutating it between runs. To my surprise the second run saw the mutated state! So I'm either completely wrong, or just wrong in the `local` mode. I hope someone can tell which. (I'll try to test this further myself if I remember tomorrow.)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  I'm somewhat surprised that it deserialize the object each time.  It looks like a feature half done to me..  It would be nice to have something like a flag on the context.broadcast(someVar, keepAlive=true)

Comment: I guess I could use a singleton object to cache broadcasted and deserialized value on each workers.

Comment: What we do for large objects is instead of using `broadcast` we just write out the object to the distributed file-system and read and cache it in the executors. The cache uses `SoftReference`, so the object will be there for the next job too, if memory pressure allows.

Comment: Can you explain me how you cache the object in the executors without using some sort of object singleton (this is not working anymore since spark 1.2.0)?

Comment: It's a simple HashMap inside a singleton object. Why would that not work since Spark 1.2.0?

Comment: According to octavian.ganea user from the spark mailing list: "The singleton hack works very different in spark 1.2.0 (it does not work if the program has multiple map-reduce jobs in the same program). ..."

Comment: Nobody in that thread knows what they are talking about except for Sean. Don't worry about it.

Comment: I experience similar behavior as I can't get spark to reuse my deserialized singleton object between commands in the shell..  Leading to gc frenzy.  It is as if captured singleton is a new one each time I execute a command on my rdd.

Comment: It may be specific to the shell. I don't exactly know how the shell sends the compiled code to the executors, but it's possible that it is the cause of the lack of reuse. Did you try it with normal compiled code? I'm almost 100% sure it works. There is just no mechanism that Spark could use to prevent the reuse. How would it find and kill your singleton? There's no way.

Comment: Looks like the singleton object works when running a job with spark-submit instead of the scala shell